# How to create private service in Angular without circular dependency

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have an `ApiService` that I don't want to share with components. It is used only inside other services.

NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'APIUrl', useValue: window.angularConfig.APIUrl },
    // ... declare secret imports like above
  ],
  exports: [
    FileService,
    FolderService,
  ],
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

Private service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: ServicesModule,
})
class ApiService {
  @Inject('secret') secret!: string;

  makeApiCall(url: string) { /* make HTTP call and send secret in header */}
}
```

Public service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: ServicesModule,
})
class PublicService {
  constructor(private api: ApiService ) {}

  getNames(url: string) {
    return this.api.makeApiCall('url/endpoint')
  }
}
```

This solution gives me an error like this:
`WARNING in Circular dependency detected:`
...\services\apis.service.ts -> ...\services.module.ts -> ...\public.service.ts -> ...\apis.service.ts`

Comment: Can you please replicate the same on to https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore I have made it, but StackBlitz shows different error... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v93qff

Comment: you can check this link i fork the code and made some changes, tried to remove errors  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-54689390

Mark useful if it help to resolve the issue.

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore Well, I wanted to "hide" `ParentService` from others, as it is meant to be private. It should only be used within `/services/`.

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore Seems like you edited your code, now it looks much better, yet I don't want to provide `APICheckSum` to root (it is used by the parent service) and I would like not to use `Injector`...